# Вызвано исключение по адресу (msvcp140d.dll)

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер

Программа определяет систему счисления по префиксам если `0x` или `0X`, то `16 СС`, так же с `2 СС`. Код одинаковый для `16 СС` и для `2 СС`, но при переходе на метку `hex` вылетает исключение. Если перейти на метку `bin` программа работает без исключений.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int number_char_lenth = 10;
    char number_char[number_char_lenth];
    int base = 0;

    fgets(number_char, number_char_lenth, stdin);

    __asm {
        xor esi, esi                    //esi = 0
        mov al, number_char[esi]        //al = первому символу в массиве
        inc esi

        cmp al, '0'                     //если al = 0, то это hex, bin, oct, если нет то 10
        je HexOrOctOrBin

        jmp de                          //10 CC


    HexOrOctOrBin:
        mov al, number_char[esi]
        cmp al, 'X'                     //если al = 'X' или 'x', то это 16 CC
        je hex
        cmp al, 'x'
        je hex

        mov bl, number_char[esi]

        cmp bl, 'B'                     //если al = 'B' или 'b', то это 2 CC
        je bin
        cmp bl, 'b'
        je bin

        jmp oct

    hex: mov base, 16
        jmp end_program

    oct: mov base, 8
        jmp end_program

    bin: mov base, 2
        jmp end_program

    de:
        mov base, 10

    end_program:
    }
    cout << base << endl;
}
```

Comment: непонятно, чего вы пытаетесь добиться вставкой `__asm`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте исключить использование дополнительного регистра:

```
HexOrOctOrBin:
    mov bl, number_char[esi]
    cmp bl, 'X'                     //если al = 'X' или 'x', то это 16 CC
    je hex
    cmp bl, 'x'
    je hex

    cmp bl, 'B'                     //если al = 'B' или 'b', то это 2 CC
    je bin
    cmp bl, 'b'
    je bin

    jmp oct
```